# VBScript for cycle does not terminate - what's causing it?

Tags: vbscript

The problem is in the second for cycle.  T does not end. I can't figure out why it does? Can you tell me what my mistake is?

```
Set Jakobi = Rastr.Tables("jakobi")
Set yzel_i = Jakobi.Cols("ni")
Set yzel_j = Jakobi.Cols("nj")
Set dp_dv = Jakobi.Cols("b")

Dim array1(50, 2), j
j = 0

Dim array_r(50, 2)
k = 0

Dim t, m
For i = 0 To Jakobi.Size - 1
    If yzel_i.Z(i) = yzel_j.Z(i) And yzel_i.Z(i) <> 0 Then
        array1(j, 0) = yzel_i.Z(i)
        array1(j, 1) = dp_dv.Z(i)
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next

k = 0
For i = 0 To Jakobi.Size - 1
    
    If yzel_i.Z(i) <> yzel_j.Z(i) Then
        
        t = 0
        m = yzel_i.Z(i)
        
        For Each x In array1
            Rastr.Printp array1(t, 0)
            If x <> m Then
                array1(t, 2) = array1(t, 2) - dp_dv.Z(i)
            End If
            t = t + 1           '<------this place
            Rastr.Printp t
        Next
        
        array_r(k, 1) = array1(t, 1) - dp_dv.Z(i)
        array_r(k, 0) = yzel_i.Z(i)
        k = k + 1
    
    End If
    
Next

For i = 0 To UBound(array1)
    Rastr.Printp array1(i, 0) & "     " & array1(i, 2)
Next
```

'The answer looks like this: I only have 25 values, and it goes to the end of the array
51
1
52
2
4
3
3
4
1
5
2
6
152
7
151
8
15
9
7
10
71
11
6
12
72
13
8
14
13
15
9
16
12
17
101
18
102
19
11
20
10
21
14
22
141
23
142
24
5
25

26

27

28

29

30

31

32

33

34

35

36

37

38

39

40

41

42

43

44

45

46

47

48

49

50

51

Comment: You should start by properly indenting your code so it's actually readable.

Comment: I apologize, but the site did not allow to leave the original tabs =(

Comment: You don't have to apologize, but I would fix it if I were you. I'm not even trying to read code formatted like this, and I'm probably not alone. So if you want people to invest their time to help you, I would suggest you invest some time to make your code readable.

Comment: "this site did not allow" - wrong. Your lack of research didn't allow it. There's Markdown that allows almost any formatting that you could need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array1` is not a Collection so you cannot use `For Each` to iterate through its values. You should simply use `t` as the counter for a regular `For...Next` loop:

```
For t = 0 To UBound(array1, 1) - 1
    Rastr.Printp array1(t, 0)
    If x <> m Then
        array1(t, 2) = array1(t, 2) - dp_dv.Z(i)
    End If
    Rastr.Printp t
Next
```